# I return nothing ondrop how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, sass, drag-and-drop, data-transfer

When iam dropping my div with an image inside i get nothing and after i am trying to get it ID i get null of course. But how can i get info from a div with image and append row with it?
Code here or check codepen:
https://codepen.io/13reathcode/pen/NWBmZpb

```
'use strict';

let queuedImagesArray = [],
    queuedForm = document.querySelector('#queued-form'),
    queuedDiv = document.querySelector('.queued-div'),
    inputDiv = document.querySelector('.input-div'),
    input = document.querySelector('.input-div input');

const colors = ['#FF7F7F', '#FFBF7F', '#FFDF7F', '#BFFF7F', '#7FFF7F', '#7FBFFF', '#7F7FFF'],
    rows = document.querySelectorAll('.content__row'),
    cards = document.querySelectorAll('.content__card'),
    addCard = document.getElementById('addCard');

// Queued Images

const onDragStart = (event) => {
    console.log('Dragging');
    event.dataTransfer.setData('id', event.target.id);

    setTimeout(() => {
        event.target.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }, 100);
};

const onDragEnd = (event) => {
    console.log('Ended dragging');
    event.target.style.visibility = 'visible';
};

const displayQueuedImages = () => {
    let images = '';
    queuedImagesArray.forEach((image, index) => {
        images += `
        <div class="image" draggable="true" id="${(Date.now() + '').slice(-10) + index}">
            <img width='100' height='100' style="pointerEvents:none;" id="${index}" ondragstart="onDragStart" ondragend="onDragEnd"
            src="${URL.createObjectURL(image)}" alt="image" />
            <span style="color:black;font-size:2rem" onclick="deleteQueuedImage(${index})">&times;</span>
        </div>
        `;
    });
    queuedDiv.innerHTML = images;
};

const deleteQueuedImage = (index) => {
    queuedImagesArray.splice(index, 1);
    displayQueuedImages();
};

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const files = input.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        queuedImagesArray.push(files[i]);
    }
    queuedForm.reset();
    displayQueuedImages();
});

inputDiv.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (!files[i].type.match('image')) return;
        if (queuedImagesArray.every((image) => image.name !== files[i].name))
            queuedImagesArray.push(files[i]);
    }
    displayQueuedImages();
});

const onDrag = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
};
// Problem here 
const onDrop = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const draggedCardId = event.dataTransfer.getData('id'); // nothing
    const draggedCard = document.getElementById(draggedCardId); // null
    event.target.appendChild(draggedCard);
};

rows.forEach((row, index) => {
    const label = row.querySelector('.content__label');
    label.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    row.ondragover = onDrag;
    row.ondrop = onDrop;
});
```

```html
<main>
            <section class="section" id="section--1">
                <div class="section__title">
                    <h2 class="section__description">Tier list app</h2>
                    <h3 class="section__text">Start dragging to move cards</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="content" id="content">
                    <div class="content__row">
                        <div class="content__label">S (The best)</div>
                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="content__row">
                        <div class="content__label">A (Great)</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content__row">
                        <div class="content__label">B (Good)</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content__row">
                        <div class="content__label">C (Mediocre)</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content__row">
                        <div class="content__label">D (Bad)</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content__row">
                        <div class="content__label">E (Horrible)</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="content__row">
                        <div class="content__label">F (Worst^_^)</div>
                    </div>  -->
                </div>
            </section>

            <form id="queued-form">
                <div class="queued-div"></div>
            </form>

            <div class="input-div">
                <p>Drag & drop images here or <span class="browse">Browse</span></p>
                <input
                    type="file"
                    class="file"
                    multiple="multiple"
                    accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg"
                />
            </div>
        </main>
```

```scss
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%; // 10px = 1rem
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.input-div {
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5rem auto;
    border: 2px dotted black;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;

    .browse {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}

.file {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.queued-div {
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 5rem auto;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px dotted black;
    background-color: white;

    .image {
        height: 10rem;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;

        &:nth-child(4n) {
            margin-right: 0;
        }

        img {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        span {
            position: absolute;
            top: -4px;
            right: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 22px;
            color: white;

            &:hover {
                opacity: 0.8;
            }
        }
    }
}

@mixin center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

// SECTIONS

.section {
    padding: 1.8rem 3rem;

    &__title {
        max-width: 80rem;
        margin: 0 auto 2rem auto;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    &__description {
        color: lightgreen;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }

    &__text {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }

    &__button {
        font-size: 2rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 3rem;
        position: relative;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        color: #fff;

        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

// CONTENT
.content {
    width: 70vw;
    min-height: 10vh;
    padding: 0rem;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    border: 3px solid #000;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 auto;

    &__row {
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        height: 8.5rem;
        background-color: #1a1a17;
        display: flex;

        &:not(:last-child) {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
        }
    }

    &__label {
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        height: 100%;
        width: 15rem;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #333;
        border-right: 3px solid #000;

        @include center;
    }

    &__card {
        @include center;

        &:focus,
        &:active {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

When i was adding images one by one everything was fine but when i changed button to input zone i can't get anything from new images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small issue in how you create your `img` elements: the `ondragstart` and `ondragend` event handlers aren't being assigned properly.

Currently, your `img` elements look something like:

```html
<img id="0" ondragstart="onDragStart" ondragend="onDragEnd" src=... />
```

However, setting `ondragstart` to equal `onDragStart` doesn't actually invoke the function when the event is fired. Same with `ondragend` and `onDragEnd`. To do so, you have to actually invoke the functions with `onDragStart(event)` and `onDragEnd(event)`.

This is because every HTML event handler attribute is implicitly wrapped in:

```js
(event) => { /** the attribute value */ }
```

In other words, currently, your handlers are equivalent to:

```js
(event) => { onDragStart }
// and
(event) => { onDragEnd }
```

instead of

```js
(event) => { onDragStart(event) }
// and
(event) => { onDragEnd(event) }
```

which is given by

```html
<img id="0" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" ondragend="onDragEnd(event)" src=... />
```

So the fix is simply to fix the `img` generation code to:

```js
images += `
<div class="image" draggable="true" id="${(Date.now() + '').slice(-10) + index}">
    <img width='100' height='100' id="${index}" 
        ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" ondragend="onDragEnd(event)" 
        src="${URL.createObjectURL(image)}" alt="image" />
    <span style="color: black; font-size: 2rem" 
        onclick="deleteQueuedImage(${index})">&times;</span>
</div>`;
```